# TextBlock scroll is not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I want to make my `TextBlock` scrollable but I can't make it work. Maybe problem is in `StackPanel`?

So here is the code:

```
 <Grid Margin="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="152*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="86*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="67*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" Margin="3,6,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rssData}}"
                 SelectedIndex="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="20" Margin="3" Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <StackPanel.ScrollOwner>
                <ScrollViewer />
            </StackPanel.ScrollOwner>
            <TextBlock Margin="3" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding XPath=title, Path=InnerText}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Opacity="0.72" Text="{Binding XPath=pubDate}" />
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="3" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding XPath=description, Path=InnerText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Height="216" Width="489" AllowDrop="False" Foreground="#FF0000E7" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Problem is in this part:

```
<ScrollViewer>
             <TextBlock ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="3" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding XPath=description, Path=InnerText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Height="216" Width="489" AllowDrop="False" Foreground="#FF0000E7" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

This part of the code should be able to scroll. I can see vertical scroll bar but can't scroll. I want to be able to see in `StackPanel` as I am not allowing any changes and want read only.

Thank you

EDIT:

```
<Window x:Class="RssDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="RSS Demo" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="576" Width="521">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E2E2" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="rssData" XPath="//item" Source="http://www.hak.hr/rss/stanje/hr.xml" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" Margin="3,6,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rssData}}"
                 SelectedIndex="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="20" Margin="3" Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding XPath=title, Path=InnerText}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Opacity="0.72" Text="{Binding XPath=pubDate}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="3"
                       FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding XPath=description, Path=InnerText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Width="489" AllowDrop="False"
                       Foreground="#FF0000E7" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" />
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Paste this code to your project as this is with the rss link where I read info. Just to see what you will get

Comment: I don't seen anything weird.  The TextBlock itself makes the content readonly so I would try it outside of the StackPanel and see if the content is scrollable.

Comment: I have tried and still nothing...

Comment: Try removing StackPanel.ScrollOwner

Comment: I just made a quick wpf project and cannot get it to work either.  I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: okay. just tried what you said and it ain't working..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I had to do, hopefully you can do the same.  First I had to place the `ScrollViewer` around the `StackPanel` and then I had to remove the `Height` from the `TextBlock`.

```
     <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">   
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
           <TextBlock Text="Test" />      
           <TextBlock x:Name="test" Margin="3" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Width="489" AllowDrop="False" Foreground="#FF0000E7" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" />      
        </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>
```

EDIT

```
    <Grid Margin="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" Margin="3,6,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rssData}}"
                 SelectedIndex="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="20" Margin="3" Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding XPath=title, Path=InnerText}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Opacity="0.72" Text="{Binding XPath=pubDate}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">   
            <TextBlock Margin="3"
                       FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding XPath=description, Path=InnerText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Width="489" AllowDrop="False" 
                       Foreground="#FF0000E7" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" />      
         </ScrollViewer>        

    </Grid>
```

Some things to point out...I modified your Grid Row Heights.  * is used to denote fill and the number does not mean pixels.  So what you hd=ad does not behave like a min with resize.  Essentiall 187* does not mean a greedy 187 pixels, where the space is at least 187 pixels but will grow as needed.  Setting the three row heights to * as I did above simply gives them each a 3rd of the parent height.  If you want the 2nd row to be twice as large as the others, set the others to * and set the middle row to 2*.  Since I can't see your screen, you can adjust as needed.  You may also be interested in using Auto and size it to the content.

Here's a screenshot of it working for me:
[image: Scrollable TextBlock]

Comment: Problem is that I am tottaly new to wpf. Can you combine your code with mine above? please.

Comment: Updated code is in the Edit section.  You still may need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: hi nothing is seems to be appearing in the textblock

Comment: I didn't realize there was a RowSpan of 2 on the StackPanel located in Grid.Row 1.  I updated the code.

Comment: Still nothing, I can't see textblock area at all. Everything else is loading, only that part doesnt

Comment: Try what's there now.  I just loaded it and it's working.  One thing I did notice is in my copy and paste I accidentally malformed the xaml.  I'm surprised you didn't see a build error from it.

Comment: Another thing to consider is I have this in Grid.Row=2.  I don't know what your surrounding xaml looks like, so you may need to play with the grid row heights and container structure to ensure everything is visible.

Comment: yes I removed an backslash sign that you had inside. Code is not so big so I'll post it in the edit section. It is a already written class for rss reading. But as you see it's not working. I will paste updated code from you

Comment: Just tried what you posted and it's working here.  What elements are wrapping your grid element?  Are you sure you're not having any binding errors?

Comment: Sorry.  I must have been looking at my own when I wrote that.

Comment: hehe okay, please try my code and tell me if you see something, check this schemas in the microsoft link above...isn't that a bit old like 2006

Comment: maybe this project is a bit old

Comment: Mine still say 2006 as well.  That's auto-generated by VS 2010 so I'm not worried about it.  I'm still seeing a scrollable texblock in my project.  The only difference in content is I removed the bindings and use hardcoded text.  Do you have any binding errors in your output window?

Comment: I just added an image of it working locally.  The only thing I can think of now is the data is empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11714/discussion-between-denonth-and-josh)

Comment: You missed the `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}"` in `<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2"`.